# Can't capture a group in a string

Tags: regex, haskell

I want to capture a group in as string:

```
import Text.Regex.Posix
"somestring; somestring2=\"(.*?)\"" =~ "somestring; somestring2=\"my_super_string123\"" :: String
```

It returns an empty string `""`, as opposed to `my_super_string123` which I expect. I've tried `::[String]` and `::[[String]]` and, obviously, they were empty. Your suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have your string and your pattern swapped.  You also will want to have the return type be `[[String]]`:

```
> "somestring; somestring2=\"my_super_string123\"" =~ "somestring; somestring2=\"(.*)\"" :: [[String]]
[["somestring; somestring2=\"my_super_string123\"", "my_super_string123"]]
```

Note that I had to remove the `?` from the `.*?` part of the pattern.  [This is because POSIX doesn't support the lazy quantifier `*?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html).  You'll have to select both of the POSIX flavors from the drop downs to see, but it says both do not support the lazy quantifiers.  It's also [recommended](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) to use negation instead of laziness for regex since it improves performance over having to backtrack.  To do this, you'd have to change your pattern to

```
"somestring; somestring2=\"([^\"]*)\""
```

---

To clarify, here's the output from my GHCi:

```
> "s1; s2=\"my_super_string123\"" =~ "s1; s2=\"([^\"]*)\"" :: [[String]]
[["s1; s2=\"my_super_string123\"","my_super_string123"]]
it :: [[String]]

> "s1; s2=\"my_super_string123\"" =~ "s1; s2=\"([^\"]*)\"" :: String
"s1; s2=\"my_super_string123\""
it :: String
```

<sup>1</sup>As you can see, with the return type as `String`, it returns whatever text matches the entire pattern, not just the capturing groups.  Use `[[String]]` when you want to get the contents of the individual capturing groups.

1. I edited the contents of the string so that it would fit without having to scroll horizontally, just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: *** Exception: user error (Text.Regex.Posix.String died: (ReturnCode 13,"repetition-operator operand invalid"))

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Ah, sorry, I forgot that I got that error too.  Remove the `?` from the pattern.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Check [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) for a comparison of regex flavors.  You can select the two POSIX flavors using the drop downs, and it says that both of them do not support the `*?` lazy quantifier.

Comment: Why would I remove "?" ? I need it to be there because my_super_string_123 might or might not exist in the original string.

Comment: And I don't need it to be [[String]], I just to capture my_super_string123.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp If I copy/paste what's in my answer into GHCi with `:: [[String]]`, I get the output also in my answer.  The reason why you have to specify that the return type is `[[String]]` is that when it's `String`, your return value will be `"somestring; somestring2=\"my_super_string123\""` because it returns the match _for the whole pattern_.  When you use `[[String]]`, it'll break out the groups, and you want the matched group, not the whole matched pattern.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Also, see my edits explaining why you can't use `*?` with POSIX regex, it just isn't supported, and I also show you an alternative that should work for you.

Comment: and will the whole text (not a grouped) **always** be in the "head" of [[String]], e.g. if I want to capture 1234 then the result will be [["the whole text 1234"], [1234]] ?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp For `"the whole text 1234" =~ "1234" :: [[String]]`, the output is `[["1234"]]` because it returns only what matches the pattern, in this case `1234`.  If instead you did `"the whole text 1234" =~ "the whole (text) (.*)" :: [[String]]`, you'd get `[["the whole text 1234", "text", "1234"]]`, where the first element of the list contains the entire match followed by each of the groups in order.  You'll want to be careful though, if you just get back `[]` then that means the match failed.  I would suggest using a `case` statement to handle the different possibilities.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp The whole matched text will always be the first element in each list returned, as far as I know.  I would read the documentation to be sure, though.

Comment: Very useful answer, there are too few Haskell regex questions and it's nice to hear about the idiosyncratic details. +1 :)

Comment: @zx81 to be honest I was confused at first that it didn't work with the lazy quantifier, but the error message indicated that it might not be supported, so after a trip to my favorite website for regex reference I quickly discovered that they aren't supported at all by POSIX. A short whole later I was reading the page on quantification and saw the recommended alternative, and now I plan to stop using them all over the place in my Python code. OP want the only one to learn something about regex today.

Comment: Yes, lazy quantifiers make the engine backtrack for each char that is matched (it starts out by matching no chars because it's lazy, then attempts the next token, fails, backtracks), so negated classes are preferred when possible. :) For me what was interesting about the answer was hearing about Haskell regex in the first place—didn't know how to invoke it, didn't know it was `POSIX`-style etc. Nice research! :) I wonder if some people are using `PCRE` in Haskell, that would be a huge improvement.

Comment: @zx81 I believe there are different implementations, I currently have `Text.Regex.Posix` and `Text.Regex.TDFA` installed (not sure what packages those are from), but a quick search with `cabal` indicates that there are several packages that work with `PCRE`, specifically `regex-pcre`.

Comment: Ahh that's good to know, IMO `PCRE` is one of the top 3 engines.  :)